# CodeIgniter Restful API return json of Chinese character with incorrect format

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

The API should return a `json` format with Chinese, but when i call API, I got all Chinese character like this:

> [{"txt":"\r\n\u7533\u8bf7\u4eba\u9655\u897f\u5e7f\u836f\u5eb7\u5065\u533b\u836f\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8\u56e0\u9057\u5931\u4e0a\u6d77\u6d66\u4e1c\u53d1\u5c55\u94f6\u884c\u80a1\u4efd\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8\u5b9d\u9e21\u652f\u884c\u7b7e\u53d1\u7684\u7968\u53f7\u4e3a3100005122723877\u94f6\u884c\u627f\u5151\u6c47\u7968\u4e00\u5f20\uff08\u80cc\u4e66\u53d6\u5f97\uff09\uff0c\u51fa\u7968\u4eba\u5b9d\u9e21\u5e02\u5929\u5b89\u5de5\u8d38\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8\uff0c\u51fa\u7968\u65e5\u671f2014\u5e742\u670819\u65e5\uff0c\u5230\u671f\u65e5\u671f2014\u5e748\u670819\u65e5\uff0c\u6536\u6b3e\u4eba\u4e3a\u9655\u897f\u4e5d\u8bda\u7164\u4e1a\u53d1\u5c55\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8\uff0c\u5411\u672c\u9662\u7533\u8bf7\u516c\u793a\u50ac\u544a\uff0c\u672c\u9662\u51b3\u5b9a\u53d7\u7406\uff0c\u73b0\u4f9d\u6cd5\u4e88\u4ee5\u516c\u544a\u3002\u81ea\u516c\u544a\u4e4b\u65e5\u8d7760\u65e5\u5185\uff0c\u5229\u5bb3\u5173\u7cfb\u4eba\u5e94\u5411\u672c\u9662\u7533\u62a5\u6743\u5229\uff0c\u5c4a\u65f6\u65e0\u4eba\u7533\u62a5\u6743\u5229\uff0c\u672c\u9662\u5c06\u4f9d\u6cd5\u4f5c\u51fa\u5224\u51b3\uff0c\u5ba3\u544a\u4e0a\u8ff0\u7968\u636e\u65e0\u6548\u3002\u5728\u516c\u793a\u50ac\u544a\u671f\u95f4\uff0c\u8f6c\u8ba9\u8be5\u7968\u636e\u6743\u5229\u7684\u884c\u4e3a\u65e0\u6548\u3002","newspaper":"\u4e2d\u56fd\u6cd5\u9662\u7f51","dtepublished":"2014-03-20","dtecreated":"2014-03-25
>   11:29:14"}]

I have tried to use **CI_Controller** to query database directly, and it shows the result with correct format. So I believe it's json's issue.

I am use `UTF-8` in both database and front end, how should I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. All special characters will be encoded so it won't get messed up. Use `JSON.parse(json);` on client side to restore your chinese characters.

Have a look at: [json_encode (PHP)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and for example at [JSON.parse (JS, Mozilla Firefox)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

**EDIT**

When you want to decode json in PHP use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for you quick answer. I don't use JS in front end, the page receive json is a PHP page, do you know how can I do JSON.parse in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I was facing the same problem, but with spanish accented words, Insted of using CI_Controller class, I'm using Rest_Controller class on my restful service [codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver). What was causing the issue on my code was that I was returning directly the string wiht special characters on the response, something like this:

```
public function users_get()
{
    $this->response('string with special character such as animación',     REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

That was causing the string be returned as unicode. Instead, I wrapped the response to an array, something like this:

```
public function users_get()
{
    $data["message"] = 'string with special character such as animación';
    $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Before that I made sure to set my charset to $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8' on config.php file. That solved my special characters/accented words issue. Hope this can be useful.